# Blog about Programming tools / professional workflow

Tags: workflow, blogs, multitasking

So a few months ago I was browsing Google blogs for some filler content in my RSS reader. I don't recall any of the my searches but I did come across this unique website which interviewed all kinds of developers and their trades (some from Greasemonkey/firefox, artists, etc). The website interviewed them about their professions and then a detailed questionnaire about their tools, workflow and other task-solving methods. I've been trying to replicate my searches and prying my mind of what I was looking for or keywords that were used in the site but I have had no such luck. The website seemed pretty high-profile so I was wondering if any of you stackoverflowians might be visitors to this site or know what I am referring to.

Thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was it usesthis.com ?  Sounds like it.

Answer (score 0):

Web Programming HTML has several versions, however there is little reason for the novice to learn anything but the latest edition. Once you have mastered the basics of html, you may want to venture into some other web coding languages.